# How to get Steam to recognise previous game files from The Witcher 3?

Tags: steam, the-witcher-3

Well, I didn't know that I could use the backup tool in Steam and I didn't use it before reseting my Windows. I don't want to download The Witcher 3, neither lose my saved games, but I couldn't get Steam to recognize the files I copied from the folder /Steamapps/Common. I copied the folder back there and clicked in Intall, although it started downloading a new game. I really don't wanna download all 50GB of game again, considering I have a 10MB internet :( Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your old steam folder as a library. This should immediately make Witcher 3 playable again after a quick data integrity check.

Go to the Settings - Downloads. Click Steam Library Folders, then select your old steam folder(s).

I reinstalled Windows just a week ago. Set my old steam folder as a library and all my games worked again.

Answer (score 1):

What Dulkan said is correct, however it happenned to me once and even that did not work. (Maybe they fixed it now)

What I did at the time was simply put everything in place and launch the .exe as it will automatically 'connect' with Steam.

Comment: Please use the 'add a comment' link to comment on other users posts rather than creating new answers.

Comment: I would genuinely love to, however I don't have enough reputation for that and still thought my answer might be useful as Dulkan's approach didn't work for me. At that point I'd like to ask why you need 50 reputation to gain comment-rights anyway.

Comment: Ask on Stack Exchange Meta :D